# How to compare two array with php and ajax each time button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I stuck at PHP and Ajax Array, I am working on Quiz Program and here is how it is working or you check website:

Visit : http://social-connections.co.uk/simple_answer.html

You will see button with yes and no. Everytime button click this code execute :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.checkAnswer').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide('fast');
    var total = total_questions;
    total = total - 1;
    total_questions = total;
    $('.count_questions').html(total);
    if(total == 0) {
        $('.count_questions').parent().html('Please enter email address to finish');
    }
    $.ajax('answer.php', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'question_answer' : $(this).html()},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});})
```

And here is PHP Code.

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['feilds'])) {
    $_SESSION['feilds'] = array();
}

$answer = $_POST['question_answer'];

$output_string = array('answer'=>$answer);
array_push($_SESSION['feilds'] , $output_string );
//print_r($output_string);

include 'Quiz.php';

$dbq = new Quiz();

$dbq->ExecuteQuery('select * from quiz');

$db_result = $dbq->data;

/*for($i = 0; $i < count($dbq->data); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < count($_SESSION['feilds']); $j++) {
        $compare_result = array_diff($dbq->data[$i]['correct_answer'], $_SESSION['feilds']['answer']);
        if($compare_result) {
            echo "All Okay";
        }
    }
}*/

$result = array();
$result_session = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($dbq->data); $i++) {
    $result[] = $dbq->data[$i]['correct_answer'];
}


for($x = 0; $x < count($_SESSION['feilds']); $x++) {
    $result_session[] = $_SESSION['feilds'][$x]['answer'];
}

$result = array_diff($result, $result_session);

print_r($result);
```

?>

I want when click on button it will check clicked value with database value and if value equal then store answer and do same for other buttons.

I have tried array_diff() functions but it showing result like this :

Visit : http://tinypic.com/r/6dv67q/8

It shows all values at once.

Please help if anyone can, if need any help i will answer instantly.

Thanks

Comment: what exact value `$output_string = array('answer'=>$answer);` contain in $anwser?    and because you mentined `'question_answer' : $(this).html()}`

Comment: $answer = $_POST['question_answer'];

here i am creating accepting answer from post and then $output_string is an array that storing value from post in 'answer' key.

Comment: `question_answer' : $(this).html()` it means u assigning the html content ... can you please paste html too.. the share sample link doesn't have any ajax request...

Comment: I am opening port will take 2 minutes there you can see all code. Thanks

Comment: And you logic says that each time u make ajax request it store variable in in session n then check it against correct values by fetching it through the db..

Comment: Yes and ignore wrong answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56960/discussion-between-bhushya-and-mandeep-gill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed,

Pass two params in ajax request for

1) quiz_id

2) correct_answer //submitted by user

PHP script logic just need to check answer correct or not and add it to sessions

read `$quiz_id = $_POST['quiz_id']` and `$answer = $_POST['correct_answer']` and your sql need to be like as mentioned below (as ref. shared db info)

```
"select * from quiz where quiz_id=$quiz_id and correct_ans='$answer'"
```

hopes that help you :)